# Complicated interface logic switching between handset and tablet versions - publish 2 apps?

Tags: android

Is it possible to publish an app that will target only handsets or tablets and simultaneosly show itself appropriately in GooglePlay store ?

The thing is that logic that switches functionality between handset and tablet versions starts to be a bit complicated and messed up. For instance, in handset version ViewPager is used while in tablet - TabHost. This forces to apply if-statements and I've only started and don't think that it will look better if I continue.

This logic switching is all about the interface - backbone data operations remain intact on both versions.

What's your experience on this issue and should I consider writing two separate apps ?

Thanks.

Comment: As Sudeep pointed out the documentation, they encourage you to develop and publish a single APK. If your case is not related to over-size, consider using different layouts/ resources for different devices, if you could…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html

Develop app for handset and tablet separately with same pkg name.

All APKs you publish for the same application must have the same package name and be signed with the same certificate key.

Each APK must have a different version code, specified by the android:versionCode attribute.

Each APK must not exactly match the configuration support of another APK.
That is, each APK must declare slightly different support for at least one of the supported Google Play filters (listed above).

Usually, you will differentiate your APKs based on a specific characteristic (such as the supported texture compression formats), and thus, each APK will declare support for different devices. However, it's OK to publish multiple APKs that overlap their support slightly. When two APKs do overlap (they support some of the same device configurations), a device that falls within that overlap range will receive the APK with a higher version code (defined by android:versionCode).